# Visual Studio Reports an Error After Pulling the Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

After I reinstalled Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10 after reinstalling the system, and pulled the project on github, but such an error occurred

`Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers with version 2.2.6 was not found. It may have been removed after a NuGet restore. Otherwise, the NuGet restore may only be partially completed, which may be due to the maximum path length limit`

I downloaded the 2.2 SDK file and installed it, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. According to [Error NETSDK1064 Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers, version 3.1.2 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restr actions .](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/16160). It should be because you did not use the administrator account after reinstalling the system, and your own account does not have write access to the project directory.
2. If the above method still does not work, please refer to the problem with the environment variable.

Please execute "dotnet --info" in cmd, please remember the base path.

[image]

Then use this path to check whether your SDK 2.2 is under this path. For example, mine is C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2